# How to self-join/merge rows based on ID? R Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some ugly data that I'm working with that looks like this.

[image]

My Goal is to get this

[image]

Here is my code and I tried doing an inner_join and full_join but I couldn't get only 3 rows.

```
data <- data.frame("ID" = c(11,11,22,22,33,33),
           "Time 1" = c(131, NA, NA, NA, 177, 177),
           "Time 2" = c(NA, 145, 342, 342, NA, 187),
           "Time 3" = c(NA, 165,NA, 412, 212, 212))

data <- inner_join(data, data, by = "ID")
```

Comment: in the expected Time.1 for 22 is 342 but it is all NA

Comment: Hey @akrun I saw that - it was an error on my end but I have fixed the table

Comment: Also, why is NA for 11 at Time.2

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA_real_ else .[complete.cases(.)][1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% fill(value, .direction = "up") %>% ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value", values_fn = max)
```